# Multiple @ElementCollection fields with discriminator?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to have a Game entity that has two List of player IDs stored as Longs

This is my table: game_player_team

| game_id | player_id | team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | H |
| 1 | 2 | H |
| 1 | 3 | A |
| 1 | 4 | A |

And this is how far I got modeling the Game entity

I can't work out how to get only the player_id's for the team H row and player_id's for the team A rows in to homePlayerIds and awayPlayerIds respectively.

I've seen the @Discriminator annotations but they only seem to work inheritence.

```java
@Entity
class Game {
    
    @Id
    private Long id

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="game_player_team", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="game_id")})
    @Column(name="player_id")
    private List<Long> homePlayerIds;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="game_player_team", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="game_id")})
    @Column(name="player_id")
    private List<Long> awayPlayerIds;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@Where annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-where), but because you are using `@CollectionTable`, you need to change the mapping a bit.

This mapping will work:

```
    @Entity
    class Game {

        @Id
        public Long id;

        @ElementCollection
        @CollectionTable(name="game_player_team", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="game_id")})
        @Column(name="player_id")
        @Where(clause = "team = 'H'")
        public List<Player> homePlayerIds;

        @ElementCollection
        @CollectionTable(name="game_player_team", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="game_id")})
        @Where(clause = "team = 'A'")
        @Column(name="player_id")
        public List<Player> awayPlayerIds;
    }

    @Embeddable
    class Player {
        @Column(name = "player_id")
        public Long playerId;
        public String team;

        public Player() {
        }

        public Player(Long playerId, String team) {
            this.playerId = playerId;
            this.team = team;
        }
    }
```

Note that for associations, one would normally use `@WhereJoinTable` but, when I've tested it, it didn't work with `@CollectionTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like this:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;


@Entity
class Game {
    
    @Id
    private Long id

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "game_player_team", 
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id"))
    @Where(clause = "team = 'H'")
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    private List<Long> homePlayerIds;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "game_player_team", 
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id"))
    @Where(clause = "team = 'A'")
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    private List<Long> awayPlayerIds;
}
```

See also [this part](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-where) of hibernate documentation.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work in this case because `team`  is part of a bridge table

Comment: @DavideD'Alto Oh, I've missed it. We should use `@WhereJoinTable` instead of `@Where` in this case, as it is mentioned [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-where-join-table). I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I’ve tried that as well, but it doesn’t work